# How to trigger rhs of a map?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
function! Foo()
  echom 'foo'
endfunction
```

And a map like this:

```
nmap gf :<C-U>call Foo()<CR>0v$
```

When I type `gf` I see `foo` echoed and the current line is highlighted.  So far, so good.

I want to be able to execute the rhs of the map without using the lhs.  Since the rhs is processed as if typed, I tried this:

```
let rhs = maparg('gf', 'n')
execute 'normal!' rhs
```

But it doesn't appear to do anything.  I also tried:

```
call feedkeys(rhs, 'xt')
```

But that didn't work either.

(My motivation is wanting to override a mapping by setting a new rhs which calls a function which can fall back to the original rhs when need be.)

How can I invoke the original rhs?

Thank you!

Comment: From `:h maparg()` "The returned String has special characters **translated** like in the output...". That is, it returns `<C-U>` as five chars, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (My motivation is wanting to override a mapping by setting a new rhs which calls a function which can fall back to the original rhs when need be.)

First, save all the information about the original mapping via `maparg()`.  To do so, you need to pass the optional boolean arguments `{abbr}` and `{dict}`:

```
let s:gf_mapsave = maparg('gf', 'n', v:false, v:true)
```

Then, in your new mapping – which overrides the original one – do whatever you want.  And when you need to invoke the original mapping, use `mapset()` to temporarily restore it:

```
call mapset('n', v:false, s:gf_mapsave)
```

Feed the lhs into the typeahead buffer:

```
call feedkeys('gf', 'xt')
```

And restore your overriding mapping:

```
nno gf :call Override()<cr>
```

As an example:

```
fu Foo()
    echom 'foo'
endfu

nno gf :<c-u>call Foo()<cr>
let s:gf_mapsave = maparg('gf', 'n', v:false, v:true)

nno gf :call Override()<cr>
fu Override()
    try
        echom 'working'
        not_working
    " fall back
    catch
        call mapset('n', v:false, s:gf_mapsave)
        call feedkeys('gf', 'xt')
        nno gf :call Override()<cr>
    endtry
endfu
```

This requires the patch [8.2.0807](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0807).

For more info, see:

- [:h maparg()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#maparg())
- [:h mapset()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#mapset())

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know about mapset() and it makes things much easier.  It still surprises me that there isn't a way to trigger a mapping's rhs without having to go through the lhs...

Answer (score 0):

In a plugin, I have a `lh#bracket#enrich_imap()` function that I use to execute some action if a condition is found true, and trigger the previous mapping/default expected behaviour otherwise.

For instance, I use it in the following way:

```
call lh#brackets#enrich_imap('<cr>',
        \ {'condition': 'getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}"',
        \   'action': 'lh#brackets#_add_newline_between_brackets()'},
        \ 0
        \ )
```

Internally, I use `maparg()` to fetch the previous mapping if any. Then, I take care with some old portable functions to correctly handle calls to script-local functions, and to build the appropriate mapping.

The main functions are

```
" from lh-vim-lib
function! lh#mapping#_build_rhs(mapping_definition) abort
  call lh#assert#value(a:mapping_definition)
        \.has_key('rhs')
  " Inject the right SNR instead of "<sid>"
  let rhs = substitute(a:mapping_definition.rhs, '\c<SID>', "\<SNR>".get(a:mapping_definition, 'sid', 'SID_EXPECTED').'_', 'g')
  return rhs
endfunction

function! lh#mapping#_switch(trigger, cases) abort
  return lh#mapping#_switch_int(a:trigger, a:cases)
endfunction

function! lh#mapping#_switch_int(trigger, cases) abort
  for c in a:cases
    if eval(c.condition)
      return eval(c.action)
    endif
  endfor
  return lh#mapping#reinterpret_escaped_char(eval(a:trigger))
endfunction

function! lh#mapping#reinterpret_escaped_char(seq) abort
  let seq = escape(a:seq, '"\')
  exe 'return "' .
        \   substitute( seq, '\\\\<\(.\{-}\)\\\\>', '"."\\<\1>"."', 'g' ) .  '"'
endfunction

-------

" from lh-brackets
function! lh#brackets#enrich_imap(trigger, case, isLocal, ...) abort
  " - Some keys, like '<bs>', cannot be used to code the default.
  " - Double "string(" because those chars are correctly interpreted with
  " lh#mapping#reinterpret_escaped_char(eval()), which requires nested strings...
  if a:0 == 0
    let previous = maparg(a:trigger, 'i', 0, 1)
    if !empty(previous) && previous.expr
      " If not an expression, I do know yet how to forward a non expr mapping
      " from an expr mapping definition
      let default = lh#mapping#_build_rhs(previous)
    else
      let default = string(a:trigger)
    endif
  else
    let default = string(a:1)
  endif
  let sCase='lh#mapping#_switch('.string(default).', '.string([a:case]).')'
  call s:DefineImap(a:trigger, sCase, a:isLocal)
endfunction

function! s:DefineImap(trigger, inserter, isLocal) abort
  if exists('*IMAP') && a:trigger !~? '<bs>\|<cr>\|<up>\|<down>\|<left>\|<right>'
    if a:isLocal
      call IMAP(a:trigger,  "\<c-r>=".a:inserter."\<cr>", &ft)
    else
      call IMAP(a:trigger,  "\<c-r>=".a:inserter."\<cr>", '')
    endif
  else
    call s:DefineMap('inore', a:trigger, (a:inserter), a:isLocal, 1)
  endif
endfunction

function! s:DefineMap(mode, trigger, action, isLocal, isExpr) abort
  " The actual definition does much more as mappings from the plugin can be activated or deactivated
  let crt_mapping = {}
  let crt_mapping.lhs     = escape(a:trigger, '|') " need to escape bar
  let crt_mapping.mode    = a:mode
  let crt_mapping.rhs     = a:action
  let crt_mapping.buffer  = a:isLocal ? '<buffer> ' : ''
  let crt_mapping.expr    = a:isExpr  ? '<expr> '   : ''
  call s:Map(crt_mapping)
endfunction

function! s:Map(m) abort
  " Nowadays there exists a vimscript function that does the same; we no longer need :exe
  let cmd = a:m.mode.'map <silent> ' . a:m.expr . a:m.buffer . a:m.lhs .' '.a:m.rhs
  call s:Verbose(cmd)
  exe cmd
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you – that's some impressive escaping!  The fact that it takes so much code shows, I suppose, that it's not easy to invoke the rhs of a map without using the lhs, which still surprises me.

Comment: The escaping part is some 20ish years old code that I use to define complex mappings with expressions like `{}<left>`  written as `{}\<left\>` to avoid troubles with `:exe`  and some other things I've forgotten. It's likely to be useless in your current use case.
These functions as used in other situations where the escaping is required.

Comment: Regarding the biggest difficulty of using the rhs, i'd say it's about correctly handling the SNR part.